# Core Data: New added objects are not being added to the end of the array when getting the NSFetchRequest

Tags: core-data, swift

Whenever I add a new object to core data, and get the results using a NSFetchRequest, the array it returns is not in the order of which I added the objects. Is this supposed to be like this? How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, data stored in CoreData is not ordered in any way. If you want it ordered, you need to add an attribute that you want to sort on and then add a sort descriptor to the fetch request.